# How can I allow a non-Outlook user to view my Outlook 2010 calendar entries?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, calendar

A colleague with no interest in installing or running Outlook needs to have read access to my Outlook 2010 calendar entries, including all updates I make. Is there a way to have Outlook automatically mirror my calendar to a web site or something similar so that my colleague can view it? For this to be practical, the syncing between my copy of Outlook and the view accessed by my colleague would need to be automatic; I don't want to have to manually push changes from within Outlook.

An alternative would be some kind of Windows app that my colleague could run that would permit her to remotely view my calendar.

Comment: Are you using Exchange as your email server ?

Comment: No. [Obligatory characters to make superuser happy]

Answer (score 0):

I personally recommend you to create the Outlook.com account and share your Outlook calendar with Outlook.com. This way you'll be able to [share your Outlook calendar with other users](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Share-an-Outlook-for-Windows-calendar-on-Outlook-com-25cd2b28-9237-4657-9623-7c55cfd818cb).

Comment: I tried this, but changes I make to my calendar in Outlook don't show up at outlook.com. I don't see anything in the outlook.com settings that looks relevant. Is there something special I need to do to have the calendar at outlook.com automatically reflect changes I make in Outlook running on my PC?

Comment: I don't think its possible to automatically synchronize your local Outlook calendar with Outlook.com. In this case it's better to use Outlook.com calendar as your primary calendar.